# How to get all journal messages before rotating?

Tags: linux, journalctl

Our embedded systems rotate journal messages according to a configured file size. I developed a tool that uploads journal messages to another system. I want to trigger this tool before rotation. But it is possible that the tool can not get some messages due to earlier rotation.

How can I synchronize my tool with rotation time?

How can I trigger upload-tool just before rotation?

Does systemd have some notify mechanism?

Comment: Are you speaking of literal cronjobs or systemd timers? Cause if it’s timers, you should be able to define two oneshot services – e. g. ``upload.service`` and ``rotate.service`` –, let the time trigger only ``rotate.service``, and have ``upload.service`` contain a dependency ``After=rotate.service``.

Comment: I am sorry, it rotates according to journal file-size, not time-based. There is no cronjob explicitly for rotation. I will edit the question.

Comment: To me it looks like you want the upload to be invoked *after* rotation on the last log that was finalized. I’m not aware of a mechanism built into journald that would allow hooking into rotation but if that is an option for you, you may be able to cook something up listening with inotifywait on the journal directory for newly created files.

Comment: Could you rename the program file that is run when the file size gets large enough to something.else and then make a script with the former name of that program and have it do what you want first then call something.else? Or if it is a subroutine, modify the subroutine to do the same thing.